# capture all visible text from a webpage using webdriver

Tags: automation, webdriver

I want to capture all text from a webpage , 
i have tried to get it by using 
(objDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body"))).getText();
i got the text but it is not able to capture the fly-out menu navigation links .

Answer (score 0):

If you need absolutely all the text in the html, you can use:

```
objDriver.getPageSource();
```

Unfortunately, if you want the page text without all the tags as well, you will probably need to call a javascript function directly, since `getText()` will only return visible text (why the menu navigation links aren't showing up for you).

To use javascript:

```
JavascriptExecutor jscript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object retVal = jscript.executeScript("$('html').text()");
if (retVal != null) {
    return retVal.toString();
}
```